# How to find the formula of the summation of i(i + 1) over 1 to N using Induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation, recurrence-relations, solution-verification

I am trying to solve a problem that requires me to find the formula for the summation of i(i + 1) from 1 to n (link to picture below) using Induction. I have no clue where to even start and I am a little frustrated. Any help is much appreciated.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhIOl.png)

Comment: Using the hint given in your picture, you can transform this into a telescoping sum. Do you see how ?

Comment: This is a basic sum which you ought to know by heart. It is easy to generalise to $k$ factors and easy to prove by induction.

Comment: @almagest Can you show me? I am familiar with induction but I cannot seem to do this. I would really appreciate your help

Comment: @Suzet I am not familiar with what a telescoping series is. I am trying to do this using induction

Comment: @jewelltaylor9430 Ok, proof of general case by induction is in answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Let g(x)=(1/3)(x+1)x(x-1). Then g(i+1)-g(i)=(i+1)i and thus
$$\sum_{i=1}^N (i+1)i= \sum_{i=1}^N( g(i+1)-g(i))  $$ $$= g(N+1)-g(1) $$
$$=(1/3)(N+2)(N+1)N-(1/3)(2)(1)0 $$ $$=(N+2)(N+1)N/3 $$

Comment: WHere are you getting g and how do you know g(i+1)-g(i)=(i+1)i  and how did you think of approaching the problem this way

Comment: The general definition of falling factorial is h(x)= x^(m)=x(x-1)...(x-m+1). Then h(x+1)-h(x)=mx^(m-1) . Let m=3, either replace x by i+1 or replace i+1 by j in the original summation. Look up falling factorials, conversion between polynomials in falling factorials and ordinary polynomials by Stirling numbers of the first and second kind,  the forward difference operator , the calculus of finite differences, and telescoping series and you can sum many series.

Answer (score 0):

*Another way to do it without using the hint*

Consider
$$S_N=\sum_{i=1}^N (i+1)i x^i=\sum_{i=1}^N [i(i-1)+2i] x^i=\sum_{i=1}^N i(i-1) x^i+2\sum_{i=1}^N i x^i$$ Rewrite it as
$$S_n=x^2\sum_{i=1}^N i(i-1) x^{i-2}+2x\sum_{i=1}^N i x^{i-1}=x^2 \left(\sum_{i=1}^N x^{i} \right)''+2x \left(\sum_{i=1}^N x^{i} \right)'$$ when finished, make $x=1$ (you will need to compute a limit).

Comment: I am looking for an anwser using induction this is too over my head

Answer (score 0):

The general case is $$\sum_{r=1}^nr(r+1)(r+2)\dots(r+k)=\frac{1}{k+2}n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k+1)$$

For $n=1$ this is just: $$1\cdot2\cdot3\dots(k+1)=\frac{1}{k+2}1\cdot2\dots(k+2)$$ which is obviously true.

Suppose the result holds for $n$.

To establish it for $n+1$ we need to show that $$\frac{1}{k+2}(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k+2)=$$ $$\frac{1}{k+2}n(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k+1)+(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k+1)$$ Taking out the common factor $(n+1)\dots(n+k+1)$ from both sides, that is just

$$\frac{n+k+2}{k+2}=\frac{n}{k+2}+1$$ which is obviously true. So the result holds for $n+1$ and hence for all $n\ge1$.

Comment: What is the formula that you are suggesting is the answer?

Comment: It is in the first line! Notice it has a extra term $n+k+1$ and a factor $\frac{1}{k+2}$.

Comment: I am confused about what k is and why you are saying (+1)(+2)…(+), the question concerns the summation of i(i+1)  from 1 to N so like 1(1 + 1) + 2(2 + 1) etc...

Comment: You asked about the case $k=1$,  ie $\sum r(r+1)$. But one can just as easily do $\sum r(r+1)(r+2)$ or $\sum r(r+1)(r+2)(r+3)$. So I proved the general case.

Comment: DId you click on the picture to see the question? I am not sure you are answering the right question or I am just lost as to what you are saying the summation is not of the form r(r+1)(r+2)

Comment: I figured it out the answer is (+2)(+1)/3 thanks for your help tho, Ill post the solution later